# header and footer dont slide with page in jquery mobile

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am creating android app using phone-gap / cordova 2.9.0 with jquery mobile 1.4.
I am using slide transition for navigation but when i navigate, page body moves properly as desired but header and footer doesn't slides. They changes after slide animation completed without any effect.
How to resolve this? Please help!!!

this is my first page
        
    
    
    
    Location Preferences

```
<script src="yorkJs/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="yorkCss/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/yorkchiller.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/core/iscroll.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/core/iscroll.stickyheaders.js"></script>
<script src="yorkJs/yorkFilters.js"></script>
<script src="yorkJs/yorkSelectionParameters.js"></script>

<script src="yorkJs/YorkChillerMain.js"></script>
<script src="yorkJs/yorkModelSpecification.js"></script>


 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/yorkchiller2.css" />

 <script type="text/javascript">
$.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'slide';

$(document).bind('mobileinit', function () {
    $.mobile.activeBtnClass = 'unused';
    $.mobile.touchOverflowEnabled=true;
});

</script>




<script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap/cordova.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/biz/EmailComposer.js"></script>
</head>

<body >

<div  data-role="page" id="selectionParameters" style="height:100%;">

    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" id="header">
        <div style="vertical-align: middle;padding-top:3px; padding-bottom:4px;" align="center">
            <img src="images/York_Logo.png" align="middle" height="30px" width="110px" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div role="main"  class="ui-content" >
        <div  style="height:auto; background-color:white">




        <div data-role="tabs" >
            <div data-role="navbar" class="custom-navbar" id="chillertypeNavbar">
                <ul>
                    <li class="ui-block-a-custom" id="liAll" value="0"><a href="#fragment-1"  id="custom-li-1" class="ui-btn-active custom-ui-a1 ui-btn-nopadding">All</a></li>
                    <li class="ui-block-b-custom" id="liAir" value="1"><a href="#fragment-2" id="custom-li-2" class="custom-ui-a2 ui-btn-nopadding" >Air Cooled</a></li>
                    <li class="ui-block-c-custom" id="liWater" value="2"><a href="#fragment-3" id="custom-li-3" class="custom-ui-a3 ui-btn-nopadding" >Water Cooled</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div id="divpreferences" >
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="listPreferences">
                <li class="ui-corner-all1" style="height:80px !important;" id="capacitylink">
                <a href="yorkCapacitySelection.html" data-transition="slide"  data-prefetch class="custom-list-a1" style="vertical-align: middle;border-top-width: 0 !important;">
                        <img src="yorkImages/Capacity.png" class="imgLocationIcon" width="45px" height="auto" style="padding-left:0px; padding-top:4px;">
                        <span class="ui-li-count ui-li-count-cutom" style="color:#3388CC; font-weight:700; border: none;" id="selPercentage"></span>
                        <p style="font-size:18px;font-weight:normal;vertical-align: middle;padding-top: 20px;margin-left:-0.7em !important;">Capacity / Tolerance</p>


                        <p style="font-size:12px;font-weight:lighter;vertical-align:middle; width:200px; margin-left:-1em !important; " id="selCapacity">Select chiller capacity and tolerance</p>



                </a>
                <div style="width:80%; height:1px; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD;float:right; ">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="newrow">&nbsp;</div>
                </li>

                <li class="ui-corner-all1" id="voltagelink">
                    <a href="yorkVoltageSelection.html" data-transition="slide" data-prefetch class="custom-list-a2" style="border-top-width: 0 !important;border-bottom-width: 0 !important">
                        <img src="yorkImages/Line_Frequency.png" class="imgLocationIcon" width="45px" height="auto" style="padding-left:0px; padding-top:4px;">
                        <p style="font-size:18px;font-weight:normal;vertical-align:middle;padding-top: 20px; margin-left:-0.7em !important;">Line Frequency / Voltage</p>

                        <p style="font-size:12px;font-weight:lighter;vertical-align:middle; width:250px; margin-left:-1em !important;" id="selVoltage">Select chiller line frequency and voltage</p>



                </a>
                <div style="width:80%;height:1px; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD;float:right; ">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="newrow">&nbsp;</div>
                </li>


                <li class="ui-corner-all1" data-icon="false">
                    <a href="" style="border-top-width: 0 !important;border-bottom-width: 0 !important; border:0; background-color:white">

                            <p style="word-break: normal; white-space: normal; font-size:12px;font-weight:lighter;vertical-align:middle; padding-left:10px; margin-left:-1em !important;"> NOTE: Chillers shown are available only in the United States and Canada </p>
                         </a>
                    <div style="width:100%;height:1px; border-bottom: 0px solid #DDDDDD;float:right;">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="newrow">&nbsp;</div>
                </li>


            </ul>
        </div>





            </div>


<div id="bottomBtn" style="bottom:36px; z-index:1; float: left; position: fixed; padding-left:5px;padding-right: 5px;width: 100%; background-color:white;"> <!-- bottom:36px -->
<!--<input value="Search Fillter" type="button" onclick="yorkChillerList.html" style="width: 100%"> -->
<a href="" id="btnSearchFilter" data-role="button" style="position:relative; display:none; z-index:1;   background: #3c92cb; color: white; font-size:20px;font-weight:500; padding-top:0.4em !important; padding-    bottom:0.4em !important;">Search Chillers</a>
</div>
</div>



 <div data-role="popup"  data-history="false" data-dismissible="false" id="about" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-all" data-overlay-theme="b" style="background-color:#E8E8E8; border-top-right-radius:7px !important; border-top-left-radius:7px !important; border:7px #000000" >
            <form>
                <div style="font-size:14px;padding:15px;text-align:center; border-radius:7px; width:100%;font-weight:normal; background-color:#E8E8E8;">
                    Chillers shown are available only in the United States and Canada

                </div>
                <div style="background-color:#E8E8E8; color:#007BFF !important; border-top:1px solid #c2c2c2; padding:10px; text-align:center; border-bottom-right-radius:7px !important; border-bottom-left-radius:7px !important;">
                    <a href="#" style="text-align:center;" data-rel="back">OK</a>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>


<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" id="footer"   data-theme="a" data-tap-toggle="false" style="z-index:1; background-color:white;">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="" id="Homebtn" data-direction="reverse" class="ui-btn-activeown" style="padding-top:2px !important; background-image: linear-gradient(#DBD9DA, #FCFAFB) !important; height:35px !important;">
                    <img src="images/Home.png" height="25px" width="25px" alt="home">
                    <label style=" margin-top:-3px; vertical-align:middle; line-height:3px; font-size:10px !important; color:grey; font-weight:bold !important;">HOME</label>
                </a></li>

            <li><a href="yorkInfoPage.html" class="ui-btn-activeown" data-transition="slide" style="border-left-color: #AEACAD !important; padding-top:2px !important;  background-image: linear-gradient(#DBD9DA, #FCFAFB) !important;  height:35px !important; ">
                    <img src="images/info.png" height="23px" width="24px" alt="info">
                    <label style=" margin-top:-1px; vertical-align:middle; line-height:3px; font-size:10px !important; color:grey; font-weight:bold !important;">INFORMATION</label>
                </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<!-- <div class="ui-loader-background"> </div> -->

<div id="domMessage" style="display:none; " data-textonly="true" class='ui-loader ui-corner-all ui-body-b ui-loader-verbose'><h1>Chiller Models are loading</h1></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @SidM, code has added.